# ScrollView not working on emulator

Tags: android

ScrollView not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_Ezequiel_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="daniel.hangman.Ezequiel_1"
        android:background="#FFF">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:text="Ezequiel 1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Title"
                android:textColor="#324"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.29" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="409dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.74"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:text="1. Aconteció en el año treinta, en el mes cuarto, a los cinco días del mes, que estando yo en medio de los cautivos junto al río Quebar, los cielos se abrieron, y vi visiones de Dios."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_1"
                    android:tag="1_1"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@color/mp3_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_2"
                    android:tag="1_2"
                    android:text="2. En el quinto año de la deportación del rey Joaquín, a los cinco días del mes,"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@color/mp3_color"
                    android:layout_margin="10px" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="3. vino palabra de Jehová al sacerdote Ezequiel hijo de Buzi, en la tierra de los caldeos, junto al río Quebar; vino allí sobre él la mano de Jehová."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_3"
                    android:tag="1_3"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="  4. Y miré, y he aquí venía del norte un viento tempestuoso, y una gran nube, con un fuego envolvente, y alrededor de él un resplandor, y en medio del fuego algo que parecía como bronce refulgente,"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_4"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="5 y en medio de ella la figura de cuatro seres vivientes. Y esta era su apariencia: había en ellos semejanza de hombre."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_5"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:background="#FFF"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 6. Cada uno tenía cuatro caras y cuatro alas."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_6"
                    android:tag="1_6"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="@color/mp3_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 7. Y los pies de ellos eran derechos, y la planta de sus pies como planta de pie de becerro; y centelleaban a manera de bronce muy bruñido."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_7"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 8. Debajo de sus alas, a sus cuatro lados, tenían manos de hombre; y sus caras y sus alas por los cuatro lados."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_8"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:text=" 9. Con las alas se juntaban el uno al otro. No se volvían cuando andaban, sino que cada uno caminaba derecho hacia adelante."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_9"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 10. Y el aspecto de sus caras era cara de hombre, y cara de león al lado derecho de los cuatro, y cara de buey a la izquierda en los cuatro; asimismo había en los cuatro cara de águila."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_10"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 11. Así eran sus caras. Y tenían sus alas extendidas por encima, cada uno dos, las cuales se juntaban; y las otras dos cubrían sus cuerpos."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_11"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 12. Y cada uno caminaba derecho hacia adelante; hacia donde el espíritu les movía que anduviesen, andaban; y cuando andaban, no se volvían."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_12"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 13. Cuanto a la semejanza de los seres vivientes, su aspecto era como de carbones de fuego encendidos, como visión de hachones encendidos que andaba entre los seres vivientes; y el fuego resplandecía, y del fuego salían relámpagos."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_13"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 14. Y los seres vivientes corrían y volvían a semejanza de relámpagos."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_14"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 15. Mientras yo miraba los seres vivientes, he aquí una rueda sobre la tierra junto a los seres vivientes, a los cuatro lados."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_15"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 16. El aspecto de las ruedas y su obra era semejante al color del crisólito. Y las cuatro tenían una misma semejanza; su apariencia y su obra eran como rueda en medio de rueda."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_16"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 17. Cuando andaban, se movían hacia sus cuatro costados; no se volvían cuando andaban."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_17"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 18. Y sus aros eran altos y espantosos, y llenos de ojos alrededor en las cuatro."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_18"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 19. Y cuando los seres vivientes andaban, las ruedas andaban junto a ellos; y cuando los seres vivientes se levantaban de la tierra, las ruedas se levantaban."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_19"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 20. Hacia donde el espíritu les movía que anduviesen, andaban; hacia donde les movía el espíritu que anduviesen, las ruedas también se levantaban tras ellos; porque el espíritu de los seres vivientes estaba en las ruedas."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_20"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" Cuando ellos andaban, andaban ellas, y cuando ellos se paraban, se paraban ellas; asimismo cuando se levantaban de la tierra, las ruedas se levantaban tras ellos; porque el espíritu de los seres vivientes estaba en las ruedas."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_21"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 22. Y sobre las cabezas de los seres vivientes aparecía una expansión a manera de cristal maravilloso, extendido encima sobre sus cabezas."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_22"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 23 Y debajo de la expansión las alas de ellos estaban derechas, extendiéndose la una hacia la otra; y cada uno tenía dos alas que cubrían su cuerpo."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_23"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 24. Y oí el sonido de sus alas cuando andaban, como sonido de muchas aguas, como la voz del Omnipotente, como ruido de muchedumbre, como el ruido de un ejército. Cuando se paraban, bajaban sus alas."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_24"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 25. Y cuando se paraban y bajaban sus alas, se oía una voz de arriba de la expansión que había sobre sus cabezas."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_25"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                android:text=" 26. Y sobre la expansión que había sobre sus cabezas se veía la figura de un trono que parecía de piedra de zafiro; y sobre la figura del trono había una semejanza que parecía de hombre sentado sobre él."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_26"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 27. Y vi apariencia como de bronce refulgente, como apariencia de fuego dentro de ella en derredor, desde el aspecto de sus lomos para arriba; y desde sus lomos para abajo, vi que parecía como fuego, y que tenía resplandor alrededor."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_27"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:text=" 28 Como parece el arco iris que está en las nubes el día que llueve, así era el parecer del resplandor alrededor.

    Esta fue la visión de la semejanza de la gloria de Jehová. Y cuando yo la vi, me postré sobre mi rostro, y oí la voz de uno que hablaba."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_28"
                    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                    android:padding="10px"
                    android:clickable="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I still don't get the concept of ScrollView. Can you clear this up ?. I tried many different things from other posts but nothing seems to work. There was a guy from other thread who fixed this by changing the upper scrollview tag to another position.

Comment: And? Just not working? close app? what happend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your parent layout as LinearLayout and use your outer `LinearLayout` as Scroll View As Follows-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_Ezequiel_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <TextView
        android:text="Ezequiel 1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:textColor="#324"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="409dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.74"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:text="1. Aconteció en el año treinta, en el mes cuarto, a los cinco días del mes, que estando yo en medio de los cautivos junto al río Quebar, los cielos se abrieron, y vi visiones de Dios."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_1"
                android:tag="1_1"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@color/mp3_color" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_2"
                android:tag="1_2"
                android:text="2. En el quinto año de la deportación del rey Joaquín, a los cinco días del mes,"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@color/mp3_color"
                android:layout_margin="10px" />

            <TextView
                android:text="  4. Y miré, y he aquí venía del norte un viento tempestuoso, y una gran nube, con un fuego envolvente, y alrededor de él un resplandor, y en medio del fuego algo que parecía como bronce refulgente,"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_4"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px" />

            <TextView
                android:text="3. vino palabra de Jehová al sacerdote Ezequiel hijo de Buzi, en la tierra de los caldeos, junto al río Quebar; vino allí sobre él la mano de Jehová."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_3"
                android:tag="1_3"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="5 y en medio de ella la figura de cuatro seres vivientes. Y esta era su apariencia: había en ellos semejanza de hombre."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_5"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 6. Cada uno tenía cuatro caras y cuatro alas."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_6"
                android:tag="1_6"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@color/mp3_color" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 7. Y los pies de ellos eran derechos, y la planta de sus pies como planta de pie de becerro; y centelleaban a manera de bronce muy bruñido."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_7"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 8. Debajo de sus alas, a sus cuatro lados, tenían manos de hombre; y sus caras y sus alas por los cuatro lados."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_8"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />
            <TextView
                android:text=" 9. Con las alas se juntaban el uno al otro. No se volvían cuando andaban, sino que cada uno caminaba derecho hacia adelante."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_9"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 10. Y el aspecto de sus caras era cara de hombre, y cara de león al lado derecho de los cuatro, y cara de buey a la izquierda en los cuatro; asimismo había en los cuatro cara de águila."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_10"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 11. Así eran sus caras. Y tenían sus alas extendidas por encima, cada uno dos, las cuales se juntaban; y las otras dos cubrían sus cuerpos."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_11"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 12. Y cada uno caminaba derecho hacia adelante; hacia donde el espíritu les movía que anduviesen, andaban; y cuando andaban, no se volvían."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_12"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 13. Cuanto a la semejanza de los seres vivientes, su aspecto era como de carbones de fuego encendidos, como visión de hachones encendidos que andaba entre los seres vivientes; y el fuego resplandecía, y del fuego salían relámpagos."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_13"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 14. Y los seres vivientes corrían y volvían a semejanza de relámpagos."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_14"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 15. Mientras yo miraba los seres vivientes, he aquí una rueda sobre la tierra junto a los seres vivientes, a los cuatro lados."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_15"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 16. El aspecto de las ruedas y su obra era semejante al color del crisólito. Y las cuatro tenían una misma semejanza; su apariencia y su obra eran como rueda en medio de rueda."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_16"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 17. Cuando andaban, se movían hacia sus cuatro costados; no se volvían cuando andaban."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_17"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 18. Y sus aros eran altos y espantosos, y llenos de ojos alrededor en las cuatro."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_18"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 19. Y cuando los seres vivientes andaban, las ruedas andaban junto a ellos; y cuando los seres vivientes se levantaban de la tierra, las ruedas se levantaban."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_19"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 20. Hacia donde el espíritu les movía que anduviesen, andaban; hacia donde les movía el espíritu que anduviesen, las ruedas también se levantaban tras ellos; porque el espíritu de los seres vivientes estaba en las ruedas."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_20"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" Cuando ellos andaban, andaban ellas, y cuando ellos se paraban, se paraban ellas; asimismo cuando se levantaban de la tierra, las ruedas se levantaban tras ellos; porque el espíritu de los seres vivientes estaba en las ruedas."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_21"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 22. Y sobre las cabezas de los seres vivientes aparecía una expansión a manera de cristal maravilloso, extendido encima sobre sus cabezas."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_22"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 23 Y debajo de la expansión las alas de ellos estaban derechas, extendiéndose la una hacia la otra; y cada uno tenía dos alas que cubrían su cuerpo."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_23"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 24. Y oí el sonido de sus alas cuando andaban, como sonido de muchas aguas, como la voz del Omnipotente, como ruido de muchedumbre, como el ruido de un ejército. Cuando se paraban, bajaban sus alas."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_24"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 25. Y cuando se paraban y bajaban sus alas, se oía una voz de arriba de la expansión que había sobre sus cabezas."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_25"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 26. Y sobre la expansión que había sobre sus cabezas se veía la figura de un trono que parecía de piedra de zafiro; y sobre la figura del trono había una semejanza que parecía de hombre sentado sobre él."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_26"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 27. Y vi apariencia como de bronce refulgente, como apariencia de fuego dentro de ella en derredor, desde el aspecto de sus lomos para arriba; y desde sus lomos para abajo, vi que parecía como fuego, y que tenía resplandor alrededor."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_27"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:clickable="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text=" 28 Como parece el arco iris que está en las nubes el día que llueve, así era el parecer del resplandor alrededor.

    Esta fue la visión de la semejanza de la gloria de Jehová. Y cuando yo la vi, me postré sobre mi rostro, y oí la voz de uno que hablaba."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Ezequiel_1_28"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:clickable="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your solution worked; However, I would like to understand what's going on

Comment: you were using using nested linear layout inside the `scrollView` Scroll View can Hold only one ViewGroup so your ScrollView was not recognizing the inner Linear Layout .